# How to rename columns by appending the row value to the column name in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as such:

```
**A**       **B**           **C**             **Name**
Hello       No              Why               -
2           5               303               Sir
```

And I want to rename the columns by appending the row value to the column name:

```
A_Hello      B_No      C_Why      Name    
2            5         303        Sir
```

(That row will be removed after I change the column names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more general solution that would apply to a much larger dataframe without having to manually rename the columns:

```
df.columns = [col.replace('*','')+ '_' +df.iloc[0,idx] for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns)]
df = df[1:]

print(df)
#output:
  A_Hello B_No C_Why Name_-
1       2    5   303    Sir
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way of doing it. Nothing manul needed & there is no `_` after 'Name' for the last column name either.

```
name_list = []
for a,b in zip ([item.replace('*','') for item in df.columns.to_list()],df.iloc[0,:].to_list()):
    if b.isalpha():
        name_list.append(f'{a}_{b}')
    else:
        name_list.append(a)
df.rename(columns={x:y for x,y in zip(df.columns,name_list)}, inplace = True)
df = df[1:]
```

**Output**

```
A_Hello     B_No    C_Why   Name
2             5     303     Sir
```